# LINQ-TO-XML Order Xml by attribute not in top level

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file like this:

```
<Root>
    <Combination Id="A35">
       <Level Id="1">
         <Option Id="S10" Time="07:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
         <Option Id="S13" Time="08:30" Date="03-10-2013"/>
         <Option Id="S15" Time="08:30" Date="01-10-2013"/>
       </Level1>
       <Level Id="2">
         <Option Id="S25" Time="07:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
         <Option Id="S26" Time="08:30" Date="03-10-2013"/>
      </Level1>
    </Combination>
    <Combination Id="A23">
        <Level Id="1">
          <Option Id="S13" Time="09:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
          <Option Id="S8"  Time="07:30" Date="01-10-2013"/>
        </Level>
        <Level Id="2">
          <Option Id="S10" Time="07:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
          <Option Id="S13" Time="08:30" Date="03-10-2013"/>
        </Level>
    </Combination>
    .....
</Root>
```

And I'd like to order it by date and time attributes in node Option(each option ordered itself) but also ordered by the earliest value in some of the Option nodes inside Level Node with id=1 (so the order of Combination nodes change):

```
<Root>
    <Combination Id="A23">
        <Level Id="1">
          <Option Id="S8"  Time="07:30" Date="01-10-2013"/>
          <Option Id="S13" Time="09:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
        </Level1>
        <Level Id="2">
          <Option Id="S10" Time="07:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
          <Option Id="S13" Time="08:30" Date="03-10-2013"/>
        </Level1>
    </Combination>
    <Combination Id="A35">
       <Level Id="1">
         <Option Id="S15" Time="08:30" Date="01-10-2013"/>
         <Option Id="S10" Time="07:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
         <Option Id="S13" Time="08:30" Date="03-10-2013"/>
       </Level1>
       <Level Id="2">
         <Option Id="S25" Time="07:30" Date="02-10-2013"/>
         <Option Id="S26" Time="08:30" Date="03-10-2013"/>
      </Level1>
    </Combination>
     .....
</Root>
```

Is it possible to get this using LINQ2XML? Or to get the order I want date and time attributes should exist in Combination nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using LINQ to XML, however, the query is quite scary:

```cs
// load XML into XDocument instance
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");

// create new XDocument using info from the loaded one
var xDoc2 = new XDocument(
                new XElement("Root",
                    xDoc.Root
                        .Elements("Combination")
                        .Select(c => new XElement("Combination",
                                        c.Attributes(),
                                        c.Elements("Level")
                                         .Select(l => new XElement("Level",
                                                          l.Attributes(),
                                                          l.Elements("Option")
                                                           .OrderBy(o => (DateTime)o.Attribute("Date") + TimeSpan.Parse((string)o.Attribute("Time")))))))
                        .OrderBy(c => c.Elements("Level")
                                       .First(l => (int)l.Attribute("Id") == 1)
                                       .Elements("Option")
                                       .Select(o => (DateTime)o.Attribute("Date") + TimeSpan.Parse((string)o.Attribute("Time")))
                                       .First())

                                       ));

// save the new document
xDoc2.Save("Input.txt");
```